# Push and present view controllers with a single push animation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

From my navigation controller's root view controller `Root`

- I want to push a view controller `A`
- which then instantaneously presents another view controller `B`.

#### How can I do both at the same time with a single *push* animation?

*( The idea behind this is that view controller `A` allows for editing some content. If no content has been created, it needs to show view controller `B` first which allows the user to enter a title and then create the content.)*

#### What I've tried:

When I do the following in view controller `A`'s `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
if content == nil {
    let createContentViewController = // instantiate new view controller instance
    present(createContentViewController, animated: false)
}
```

*UIKit* also omits the `push` animation when `animated` is set to false – so I get no animation at all. When `animated` is set to `true`, I get a double animation (first push, then modal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble doing what you describe is that you can't `present` View Controller B on View Controller A until View Controller A is part of the view controller hierarchy — and until you have pushed it, it isn't.

I would suggest, therefore, not using a presented view controller in this story at all. All you are really describing, it seems to me, is a View Controller A and its main view (View A) with a View B in front of it. That's something you can readily prepare between creating View Controller A and pushing it. View B can still contain a Dismiss button or similar to which you respond by sliding it off the screen, revealing View A.

If you really need a View Controller B for purposes of code organization, then have View Controller A be a custom parent view controller for View Controller B. A cool feature of that solution is that the whole thing can be configured in the storyboard using an embed segue. If we push View Controller A and you *don't* need View Controller B, you just hide View B before pushing.

Comment: "Don't say yes until I've finished talking!" My third paragraph presents a further interesting possibility. :)

Comment: The first paragraph already answers my question as it states that what I'm trying to do is simply not possible. I'm not too happy with either of your suggested alternative solutions as the first is really messing with the code that clearly belongs into two different controllers and for the second I would need to put the container view on top of the other content in the storyboard, making it tedious to edit. So suggestion 1 creates chaos in code, suggestion 2 creates chaos in Interface Builder. And both solutions don't give me the built-in presentation animations for free (for dismissal).

Comment: Thanks for these two ideas but I guess I'll need to come up with a third idea. Good to know that my original approach is simply not possible to implement though!

Comment: Oh, as to that, you can do the opposite of what I said: turn A into a parent of B in code, at push time, only if B needs to show.